# Will the last entry in Guava cache be removed within a definite time?

Tags: caching, guava

We use Guava for caching with an expireAfterAccess (1 minute) strategy. Typically in the morning the cache is accessed quite often, often enough to trigger its 'best-effort' maintenance.

My question is what will happen to the **last** entry? After the last access there could be a gap up to 20 hours. Will the last entry still be removed within a 1 minute or even a couple of minutes?

Comment: If inactive, the entry will expire and not be accessible but remain in the cache. There is no built-in thread to actively remove entries. You can instead call `cleanUp()` yourself by a scheduled thread. But if the system is idle, the dormant entry should have no ill effects by retaining memory a little longer.

Comment: When the entry remains in the cache, the removal listener will NOT be called, right?

Comment: True. The cache makes no guarantees of when the listener is called, only that it will be called. If you need more timely removal this is when you can call `cleanUp` periodically from your own thread.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes, would you like to put together an answer?